# Windows Mobile 6 Emulator fails to launch Visual Studio 2008 Project

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6

Whenever i try to debug a solution for windows mobile 6 I am met with this error 
[image: visual studio error]

The project works on other machines around the office and has worked on my machine before. My guess is a setting has changed on my machine that is causing this to fail but I haven't found any solutions.

Comment: I am not sure, but have you tried to Clear the Saved State of the Emulator you use? ONTOH your code seems to interfer with someting on the emulator device, if it really works OK on other PCs.

Comment: Yea I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the emulator but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Uninstalling does not mean that Microsoft does not remember the settings. An Windows Uninstall will mostly keep application settings (unfortunately :-( ). Please try "Clear Saved State" in the emulator window. You may alos uninstall and then a regsitry and file cleaner that looks for unused directories and registry entries.

Comment: I've cleared the state dozens of time and that doesn't help. I'll try cleaning out the registry next.